# Reopening the question

Tags: support, re-open

I'm dealing with slightly disappointing situation and I decided that the best thing to do would be to ask here.
I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781033) recently. I got some helpful comments and one brilliant answer. Since it was a rather self-educational problem, I decided to solve it anyway according to pointers I got in comments (they were suggesting another approach).

When I succeed with solution, even though I accepted another answer, I decided to provide mine too. Just to let it be there, as a start of my payback to community, which provided exceptional amount of help to me during past months.
I even typed half of it, when question turned closed.
I voted to reopen, but it seems that I somehow have to get more votes to make it happen.

Also I have a feeling that this situation isn't unique, and probably asked dozen of times and covered in FAQ or somewhere else.
Please don't be hard on me, I just wanted to put a piece of hard-earned knowledge to the site I love.

Comment: You could add your answer to the question of which yours was marked a duplicate (if indeed it is a duplicate).

Comment: @robjohn They aren't exact duplicates, but they highly correlated. It would be easy to adapt the solution.
Thanks, it seems like reasonable advice. But as I get it, generally there is no easy way to reopen. So, if I'm thinking about writing my own 5 cents to the thread, it's better to just not be rushing to accept someone's answer?

Comment: The question would have been closed whether you had accepted the answer or not. However, don't give up on getting the question reopened. It often helps to post an "answer" to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) explaining why you think your question should be reopened.

Comment: In the meantime the question is reopened. @robjohn: Maybe upgrade your comment to a short answer?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I would if this question had not also been closed. :-)